# How can I set my TP-Link TL-WR1043ND to extend my router - modem range?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'd like to extend my WiFi coverage, so I've bought the TP-Link TL-WR1043ND and updated its firmware to the latest (`wr1043nv1_en_3_13_4_up(110429)`) but I can't find how to use its WDS function.

Reading further on Super User I understand that both the modem-router (Pirelli Alice Gate) and the TL-WR1043ND should support WDS. Are there any tricks to achieve the same result - extending my WiFi range - even changing the firmware to DD-WRT or Tomato etc?

Comment: You need to have the modem/router set to WDS mode and the TP-Link set to **Wireless Bridge**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More often than not, WDS requires two or more APs from the same manufacturer in order to work *properly*. This actually means both need to have firmware developed by the same vendor. So, you most likely have to flash DD-WRT (or any other 3rd-party firmware) to the Pirelli Alice Gate modem-router and TL-WR1043ND.

I know DD-WRT is compatible with TP-Link TL-WR1043ND, but I'm not sure about the other device. OpenWRT seems to be compatible with both (link [1](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr1043nd) & [2](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/pirelli/aga)), but you'll need a serial cable to flash the firmware to the Pirelli Alice Gate.

Comment: I had a USRobotics modem/router sending to a TP-Link WR743ND when both had their native firmware (albeit the latest versions of each) without any issues.

Comment: But you can't always be so lucky. That's why I said "more often than not". Some vendors even state which AP-AP combination that is guaranteed to work hassle-free for WDS.

Comment: Agreed, but I wanted to point out that it *might* just work "out of the box".

Comment: That's the saddest pain ever :(
Maybe I should sell my Pirelli Alice Gate and get a tp-link modem - router that works perfectly and out of the box with my tl-wr1043nd...
:(

Comment: Maybe adding a TD-W8961ND will do the job, right?

Comment: Yes, it probably will do the job. You must first ask your provider whether you're allowed to replace your modem-router piece. This of course, assumes you got the Pirelli Alice Gate from your internet provider. If you didn't get the thing from them in the first place and you know how to set it up, you can just go for it.

Comment: I've bought it and it worked (after a LOT of hassle) but now I've screwed up the configuration and can't do it again :(
If anybody can be of help: http://superuser.com/questions/320071/tp-link-tl-wr1043nd-tp-link-tl-w8961nd-wds-configuration-how