# How do I use a TP-Link TL-WR1043ND as a wireless extender for a TL-W8961ND?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have:

- TP-Link [TL-WR1043ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TL-WR1043ND.html), Ultimate Wireless N Gigabit Router
- TP-Link [TL-W8961ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TD-W8961ND.html), 300Mbps Wireless N ADSL2+ Modem Router

I need detailed information on how to set the TL-WR1043ND to operate as a wireless extender. Both routers are running the latest firmware. How can I do it?

Comment: Return it for a refund and buy something you can figure out. Don't reward makers of hard-to-use products with your money.

Comment: Technically a computer is a "hard to use" product so I shouldn't buy it :)
I think I just need a few hints from someone who already did wds between those routers :)
In the end I think that no company makes an easy router to router wi fi communication :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) on the TL-WR1043ND allowed me to use it as wireless extender (client bridge).
It has been quite easy and straightforward :)

> DD-WRT is a Linux based alternative OpenSource firmware suitable for a great variety of WLAN routers and embedded systems. The main emphasis lies on providing the easiest possible handling while at the same time supporting a great number of functionalities within the framework of the respective hardware platform used.